# Regex excluding a specific characters

Tags: regex, git

I have following tags available in git.

```
popup/0.0.998
popup/14.0.999
popup/54.33.99
popup/20160729/0.0.624
popup/20160730/1.55.624
popup/20160930/99.44.783
```

From these tags I want only following and exclude others tags. That is I want only tags `popup/natural_number.natural_number.natural_number` has this format.

```
popup/0.0.998
popup/14.0.999
popup/54.33.99
```

I used following command but it is still giving following tags -

Command used:`git tag -l 'popup/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'`

Giving all tags:

```
popup/0.0.528
popup/140.42.409
popup/54.323.726
popup/20160729/0.0.624
popup/20160730/1.55.624
popup/20160930/99.44.183
```

Kindly suggest, How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git tag` doesn't take a regular expression and the reason that it returns something is because it accepts filename expansions or globbing. You could use `grep` instead:

```
git tag -l | grep -P '^popup/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to escape backslashes:

```
popup/[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*
```

I've tested with `grep` and it worked:

```
$ cat tags
popup/0.0.998
popup/14.0.999
popup/54.33.99
popup/20160729/0.0.624
popup/20160730/1.55.624
popup/20160930/99.44.783
$ cat tags | grep popup/[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*
popup/0.0.998
popup/14.0.999
popup/54.33.99
```